# python key value two dict matches

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tyring to match the value of two dicts of two sperate keys by looping over them-with hopefully `if i in line_aum['id_class'] == line_investor['id_class']` becoming `True`, then the next sum dunction will work:

Tho it kicks out a different result

so far I have:

```
for line_aum in aum_obj:
    for line_investor in investor_obj:
        if i in line_aum['id_class'] == line_investor['id_class']:
            total = (sum,line_investor['amount'], line_aum['value'])
            amount = line['id_class']
            print(amount,total)
```

Example data:

```
{'fund_name': '', 'fund_code': 'LFE', 'aumc': '406.37', 'value': '500', 'ddate': '2013-01-01', 'id_fund': '165', 'currency': 'EUR', 'nav': '24.02', 'shares': '16.918', 'estimate': '0', 'id_class': '4526', 'class_name': 'LTD - CLASS B (EUR)'}
```

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Comment: line_aum['id_class']  is so non python. Yo should use line_aum.get("id_class", Default_Value_You_Want_to return)

Comment: Your `if` expression makes *no* sense. `i in foo == bar` is a chained operator, so that is interpreted as `i in foo and foo == bar` which is not what you wanted I'd say. Also, `line_aum` and `line_investor` are *keys*, what type are they that you can treat them as dictionaries?

Comment: Did you want to loop over the *values* of the 2 dictionaries instead?

Comment: And last but not least, please include some sample data.

Comment: ah, must of crossed over some R syntax-sorry-well spotted

Comment: Your sample data is missing all context. Is it one dictionary inside of `investor_obj` or `aum_obj`? Are those two objects lists or dictionaries?

Comment: missing all context, in what sense?-I am just looping over a line in each dict. Both dicts have the same key value id_class-so I am trying to find if they match.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product` instead of nested loops if both `aum_obj` and `investor_obj` are lists:

```
from itertools import product

for line_aum, line_investor in product(aum_obj, investor_obj):
    if line_aum['id_class'] == line_investor['id_class']:
        # `line_aum` and `line_investor` have matching values for the `id_class` keys.
```

Comment: {'fund_name': '', 'fund_code': 'LFE', 'aumc': '406.37', 'value': '500', 'ddate': '2013-01-01', 'id_fund': '165', 'currency': 'EUR', 'nav': '24.02', 'shares': '16.918', 'estimate': '0', 'id_class': '4526', 'class_name': 'LTD - CLASS B (EUR)'}

Comment: Martin-here is some sample data. its json from an api, so .values() spits out an attribute error.

Comment: @VivaNosh: Then either `aum_obj` or `investor_obj` are *not* dictionaries.